# Get many options commands

Tags: linux

how to get two options commands ? for example i want to get words after and before an numbered get lines. how to get both  them ?

`grep -B -A -n

Comment: I want to  use all three options  together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just use them all like

```
grep -n -B 2 -A 2 word file.txt
```

or if you want the same number of lines before and after there's a `-C` for that

```
grep -n -C 2 word file.txt
```

Comment: can you help me ? i want to show the lines which contains some words like apple, i do not want to show only words i want to show full lines.

Comment: @Irakli by default that is what `grep` does, shows the full line that contains a word or pattern.  If that's not what you're seeing, please post another question that includes sample input, the command exactly as you're running it and the output you see along with the output that you expected/wanted to see.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask